# listing objects in aws bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to print all the objects in a bucket but I am getting an error.

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code:  301, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 758A7CBF1A29FD74, AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint., S3

At the moment I only have the following code :

```
public class S3Download {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
        Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
        s3.setRegion(usWest2);
        String bucketName = "apireleasecandidate1";

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName);
        ObjectListing objectListing;

        do{
            objectListing = s3.listObjects(listObjectRequest);
            for(S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()){
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + " " + "(size = " +
            objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
            }
            listObjectRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
        }while(objectListing.isTruncated());
    }

}
```

I found [this solution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html) on amazon's website.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Do you need a Java-based solution?

Comment: YES I need a java based solution

Comment: take a look at http://s3.jcabi.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Scala developers, here it is recursive function to execute a ***full scan and map*** of the contents of an AmazonS3 bucket using the official [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{S3ObjectSummary, ObjectListing, GetObjectRequest}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{collectionAsScalaIterable => asScala}

def map[T](s3: AmazonS3Client, bucket: String, prefix: String)(f: (S3ObjectSummary) => T) = {

  def scan(acc:List[T], listing:ObjectListing): List[T] = {
    val summaries = asScala[S3ObjectSummary](listing.getObjectSummaries())
    val mapped = (for (summary <- summaries) yield f(summary)).toList

    if (!listing.isTruncated) mapped.toList
    else scan(acc ::: mapped, s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))
  }

  scan(List(), s3.listObjects(bucket, prefix))
}
```

To invoke the above curried `map()` function, simply pass the already constructed (and properly initialized) AmazonS3Client object (refer to the official [AWS SDK for Java API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)), the bucket name and the prefix name in the first parameter list. Also pass the function `f()` you want to apply to map each object summary in the second parameter list.

For example

```scala
map(s3, bucket, prefix)(s => println(s))
```

will print all the files

```scala
val tuple = map(s3, bucket, prefix)(s => (s.getKey, s.getOwner, s.getSize))
```

will return the full list of `(key, owner, size)` tuples in that bucket/prefix

```scala
val totalSize = map(s3, "bucket", "prefix")(s => s.getSize).sum
```

will return the total size of its content (note the additional `sum()` folding function applied at the end of the expression ;-)

You can combine `map()` with many other functions as you would normally approach by [Monads in Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your bucket "apireleasecandidate1" is not in the us-west-1 region. I think it is in the us-classic region. You should modify your code to remove the setRegion() call.